# How to check a program running by jar file (cmd) or on intellij (IDE)?

Tags: java, jar

I want to check a program is running by jar file (cmd) or on intellij (IDE)?

In my opinion: check if that jar file is exists or is being called?

For example:

```
if (xxx) {  //check running by jar file?
     //do something
} else {  //check running on IDE?
     //do something
}
```

Thanks for watching!!!!!

Comment: On Mac OS: Load up the environment and run the app from the terminal - check the env variable named : `XPC_SERVICE_NAME` - When run from Intellij this environment variable will indicate that.

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn! Thank you for this answer. Is there a simpler way that can be tested with regular java code? example: check if that jar file is exists or is being called?

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/e2f3e760584878f6a02e621381abd1e9) - I think it does what you are asking.